# Unable to install probufJs with node v12.6

Tags: node.js, grpc, protobuf.js

I'm trying to implement grpc web service in nodejs. While installing dependency protobufJs using npm i protobuff, I'm getting **error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Function::NewInstance()** on node version 12.13.

I have tried changing node version to 10.17 & 8.16.2.
But, every time I got the same error. The os is ubuntu 18.04.2.

I can't use protoc to generate the protocol buffers statically, because,
the company I work with wants it dynamically generated.

I'm using npm i protobuf command[image: npm i protobuf error]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very outdated implementation of protobuf in nodejs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobuf says the package was last published 2 years ago, adding support for Node v0.11.13. This is very very old...

Instead, you probably need the more maintained package `protobufjs` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs. Just run `npm i protobufjs` instead of `npm i protobuf`!